# How can I install pdfedit on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, apt

How can I install `pdfedit` on Debian Jessie? I have tried to install it with `apt-get install` but it seems it has not been updated for Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a previous version repository to `/etc/apt-get/sources.list` manually or `apt-get install python-software-properties` and then `add-apt-repository <rep that was ok with your software>`

Answer (score 0):

This package is being removed from all Debian distributions. You could however build it from source if needed:

https://sourceforge.net/p/pdfedit/git/ci/master/tree/